# How to get fix "You are not authorized to access" accessing VS Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tf-cli

I can open internet explorer and login just fine.

Credentials are saved in the credential manager.

Trying to access any tf.exe command results in a TF30063 error.

I do not have VS installed on this machine.

Any suggestions on what to try?

**UPDATE:**
Here are the step I've taken to get this error.

- Login to VS Team Services via IE
- At the command prompt:

```
C:\>tf.exe status /collection:https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
C:\>tf.exe workspaces /collection:https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com
C:\>tf.exe workspace /new /collection:https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com
```

I've also tried a few others and everyone of them return with the same unauthorized error.

These commands all work on another server that's connected to the same tfs repo with the same credentials, which leads me to believe it's something in IE and/or internet security options.

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I've tried status, get, workspaces

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Is there sign in dialog pop up when you run "tf status" command?

Answer (score 1):

Taking add files and folders to version control as example, you can specify the user account `/login:username,[password]` in the command:

```
tf add itemspec [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/encoding:filetype] 
[/noprompt] [/recursive] [/noignore] [/login:username,[password]]
```

More commands, see: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands

Comment: As you didn't install VS on your machine, did you install Team Explorer? Try to clean the cache folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache, remove the credential in the credential manager, and delete history of your browser. Disable the firewall and anti-virus software as well. Then specify /login:username to see whether you can access VSTS.

Comment: Could you show me some sample example instead of syntax

Answer (score 0):

To use tf.exe command, you need either **Visual Studio or Team Explorer is installed**. More details please refer **[Command-line tools for TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253088(v=vs.120).aspx)**